# Can't run OpenCV example in OSX Yosemite (Macbook 8,1)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I want to run OpenCV (opencv-3.0.0-beta) on OSX Yosemite with a Macbook Pro 8,1 and XCode. But I get some issues.

**Code I Used:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(){

VideoCapture cap(0);

while (true){

    Mat Webcam;
    cap.read(Webcam);
    imshow("Webcam", Webcam);

    }

}
```

**I get four issues..**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::_OutputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**The Settings for Search Paths are:**

- Always Search User Paths = Yes
- Framework Search Paths =
  /usr/local/lib
- Header Search Paths =  /usr/local/include
- Library
  Search Paths = "MyOpenCV-Folder"/build/lib

**Can anybody help?

And please tell me if you need some more information.
You'll get them :p

Thanks!**

Comment: You probably forgot to actually link against the OpenCV libraries, see e.g. [Linking the Libraries](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/)

Comment: After Linking the Libraries the build succeeded :-)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comment in an answer:

You probably forgot to actually link against the OpenCV libraries.
The libraries need to be explicitly specified, [this link](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/) shows how you need to do it in Xcode.